# On notation of an outer automorphism group of an extra-special $2$-group $2_{\pm}^{1+2n}$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

What is the correct notation for the outer automorphism group of an extra-special 2-group $2_{\pm}^{1+2n}$? Is it $O^{\pm}(2n,2)$ or the ATLAS notation $GO^{\pm}(2n,2)$? Also, I noticed that in literature that sometimes the term automorphism group instead of outer automorphism group is used. For example, in a book it is mentioned that automorphism group of $P=2_+^{1+8}$ is isomorphic to $O^{+}(8,2)$. I assumed that they meant the outer automorphism group $Out(P)\cong Aut(P)/Inn(P)$.  What will be the correct terminology?

Comment: I am afraid that the notation for groups related to the orthogonal groups over finite fields varies considerably from text to text, so it makes no sense to ask which one is correct. I prefer ${\rm GO}^{\pm}(2n,2)$, for general orthogonal group, because it is consistent with ${\rm GL}$ and ${\rm GU}$, and we can use ${\rm SL}$, ${\rm SU}$, and ${\rm SO}$ to denote their determinant one subgroups (but or course ${\rm SO} = {\rm GO}$ over ${\mathbb F}_2$). Yes, outer automorphism is intended.

Comment: To stress the point, $O^\pm_{2n}(q)$ is used for the general orthogonal group *and* the associated simple group (but hopefully not at the same time!). I avoid using $O$ for *anything* precisely because of this, and use $\mathrm{GO}$ (as Derek) for the general orthogonal group, and $P\Omega$ for the simple group.